# How would I change the color of a shape from another ComboBox (C#,Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

so what I'm trying to do is change a color of a shape using another combobox. So the first combobox represents what kind of shape will be shown as an image. For example, it will show triangle if I press on the triangle option. Well, I have another combo box that shows what kind of color the shape will be in. The code I have so far is shown here:

```
  using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBoxTest
{
   // Form uses a ComboBox to select different shapes to draw
   public partial class ComboBoxTestForm : Form
   {
      // constructor
      public ComboBoxTestForm()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

      } // end constructor
      Pen myPen;
      SolidBrush mySolidBrush;


      private void imageComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(
         object sender, EventArgs e )
      {


         // create graphics object, Pen and SolidBrush
         Graphics myGraphics = base.CreateGraphics();

         // create Pen using color DarkRed


         // create SolidBrush using color DarkRed


         // clear drawing area setting it to color white
         myGraphics.Clear( Color.White );

         // find index, draw proper shape
         switch ( imageComboBox.SelectedIndex )
         {
            case 0: // case Circle is selected
               myGraphics.DrawEllipse( myPen, 50, 50, 150, 150 );
               break;
            case 1: // case Rectangle is selected
               myGraphics.DrawRectangle( myPen, 50, 50, 150, 150 );
               break;
            case 2: // case Ellipse is selected
               myGraphics.DrawEllipse( myPen, 50, 85, 150, 115 );
               break;
            case 3: // case Pie is selected
               myGraphics.DrawPie(myPen, 50, 50, 150, 150, 0, 45 );
               break;
             case 4:
                Point point1 = new Point(150,  50);
                Point point2 = new Point(100,  150);
                Point point3 = new Point(200,   150);

                Point[] curvePoints =
                         {
                             point1,
                             point2,
                             point3,
                         };

                myGraphics.DrawPolygon(myPen, curvePoints);
               break;
             case 5: // case Filled Circle is selected
               myGraphics.FillEllipse( mySolidBrush, 50, 50, 150, 150 );
               break;
            case 6: // case Filled Rectangle is selected
               myGraphics.FillRectangle( mySolidBrush, 50, 50, 150, 
                  150 );
               break;
            case 7: // case Filled Ellipse is selected
               myGraphics.FillEllipse( mySolidBrush, 50, 85, 150, 115 );
               break;
            case 8: // case Filled Pie is selected
               myGraphics.FillPie( mySolidBrush, 50, 50, 150, 150, 0, 
                  45 );
               break;
             case 9:
                  Point point4 = new Point(150,  50);
                Point point5 = new Point(100,  150);
                Point point6 = new Point(200,   150);

                Point[] curvePoints2 =
                         {
                             point4,
                             point5,
                             point6,
                         };
               myGraphics.FillPolygon(mySolidBrush, curvePoints2);
               break;
         } // end switch

         myGraphics.Dispose(); // release the Graphics object

      }

      private void ComboBoxTestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }

      private void colorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

          switch (colorComboBox.SelectedIndex)
          {
              case 0:
                  myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
                   mySolidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                  break;
          }
      }

      // end method imageComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged
   } // end class ComboBoxTestForm
}
```

What I tried to do is call myPen outside of the void, so it can be called in the second void which controls the color. Mysolidbrush represents the filling of a shape. In the second void, I tried calling myPen to be the color black , but I saw no change. I was wondering what steps I should make so that it shows the color that I want.

Comment: Put all paint logic in `Paint` event, then in `SelectedIndexChanged` events, just call `this.Invalidate();`

Comment: Also in current code, while you have defined `myPen` and `mySolidBrush` as class members, you never initialized them. In `colorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` you are assigning local variables, not class members.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to GUI, can you show how thats done?

Comment: I shared some pseudo code for you describing the comment as you requested. Hope you find it helpful :) Don't forget to assign handlers to events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all paint logic in `Paint` event of form, then in `SelectedIndexChanged` events, just call `this.Invalidate();`:

```
private void ComboBoxTestForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //detect color based on selected index of colorComboBox
    //Create your brush and your pen
    //detect shape based on selected index of imageComboBox
    //draw shares using e.Graphics.DrawXXXX and e.Graphics.FillXXXX


   /*Suppose Color.Redis detected from selected index*/
    var myColor= Color.Red; 
    using ( var myPen = new Pen(myColor))
    {
        /*Suppose drawing ellipse is detected from selected index*/
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse( myPen, 50, 50, 150, 150 );
    }
}

private void imageComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    //Makes the form repaint
    this.Invalidate();
}
private void colorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Makes the form repaint 
    this.Invalidate();        
}
```

Also in your current code, while you have defined `myPen` and `mySolidBrush` as class members, you never initialized them. In `colorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` you are assigning local variables, not class members.

```
myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
mySolidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
```

Also in your current code, you have put all paint logic in `imageComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` and even if you correct the code in `colorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` and assign value to your class member `myPen` and `mySolidBrush`, the color of your drawing will change only for next shape.

Comment: Im not really familiar with paint events, so is there another way that I can call myPen? What I want to do for the second void is for case 0 to recognize myPen and then change the color for the 1st void. Do I just need to initialize myPen?

Comment: If you want to learn paining, you should learn to use `Paint` event. Any way, you should know you have put all paint logic in `imageComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` and even if you correct the code in `colorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` and assign value to your class member `myPen` and `mySolidBrush`, the color of your drawing will change only for next shape.

Comment: Do I need to initialize it both outside of the void and in the second void?

Comment: In the `colorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` you should not declare local variables, you should only assign values, as I did in the answer.

Comment: I did exactly that but the color does not change

Comment: Your code needs more refactoring and changes as I described in the post and I think the post answers your question :)

Comment: Is there any thing else that I can help you? I hope you get the main point :)

Comment: I did initialize in the colorcombobox, and I called myPen,solidbrush outside the void. And sorry I'm really new to GUI, just learned this a week ago

Comment: I edited the code above. Is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, but the code doesnt even show the shapes when I tried using the method you told me. It says unhandled exception has occurred in your application when I click on the combo box. It also says value cannot be null. Parameter name: pen

Comment: It seems you don't read the answer and the comments! As I said **(1)** *You never initialized them* so you should initialize them for example first in constructor. **(2)** *Even if you correct the code in colorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged and assign value to your class member myPen and mySolidBrush, the color of your drawing will change only for next shape.* and obviously its because you have drawn the previous shape with previous colors and you changed the colors just now .

Comment: Hey I got to work. But like you said, it only changes when I change the shape. Thanks for the help

Comment: You are welcome:)  I strongly recommend you to check the edit and use Paint event as I said.

Comment: By the way, when you find an answer helpful, you can kindly click on up arrow and check mark near it to vote and accept it. It's not compulsory at all, but reasonable, recommended and your kindness. It makes the question and answer more useful for future readers.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Thanks for the help once again